# Spark-phoenix : how to get data between given date range

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I am able to connect to and fetch data from phoenix using phoenix-spark connector.but I get all table data.I want to get data between two date range. For that I am using

```
val configuration = new Configuration()
    configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","host:2181")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSessionZipsExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val df = spark.sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame("BGALLSALES", Array("DIVISION","SECTION","BILLDATE","ADMSITE_CODE"),predicate = Some("BILLDATE <TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-03 00:00:00')"),conf = configuration)
```

It works but it gives me all data available in table, which is not good to load all data in spark dataframe.Is there a way I can get data between two range or less or more than that range